# Android Studio - ActionBarSherlock won't let app launch

Tags: android, intellij-idea, actionbarsherlock, android-studio

From Android Studio, I have imported a previous non-Gradle Android project from Eclipse.

It includes ABS and runs in Eclipse without problem.

It compiles error free in Android Studio. However, every single time I run it, it doesn't just run as it does in Eclipse, it goes into some test mode and gives the following output.

> Running tests
>   Test running startedTest running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.my.package/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
>   Empty test suite.

Then doesn't open up at all.

Comment: Is `com.my.package` your real package name? Verify the package specified in `AndroidManifest.xml` files, it should match in test and app modules and was probably replaced with a dummy one when importing. Compare with your original Eclipse project and fix the manifest files.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include word 'test' in your methods I have faced it and have to name all methods like testIfOneIsOne or OneIsOneTest(not sure now what order I used).
Also: Are You use same version of junit on both eclipse/intelij?

Comment: Well I ideally don't really want any testing right now, not overly familiar with it and will get some testing going in due time. At the moment, I have deleted the test directory and just want it to go away and be like Eclipse :) Eclipse doesn't show a test directory like Android Studio. You are suggesting I rename all my methods and include "test" in them? Any elaboration on that? Again, I want to try and avoid all testing right now, it is early stages

Comment: @migbson You are using maven or ant to build app?

Comment: Neither, I had a straightforward Eclipse project which worked great. I imported that project from Existing Source into Android Studio.. however when I run it in AS, It always comes up with these test messages that just don't exist when I run it in Eclipse

Comment: @migbson Have You checked configuration after import(I know that import from eclipse doesn't have to go well), also unchecking test as testfolder in project settings doesn't help(ctrl+alt+shift+s)->sources?

Comment: I checked the config, test was there in the ABS source albeit red, so I deleted that. Strangely when I look at the src of my app, it is all excluded.. seemingly won't change either.

Answer (score 0):

try checking my solution here. ABS includes junit which might be running for you. Try following my solution here:
[Problems importing project into Android Studio regarding ActionBarSherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577580/problems-importing-project-into-android-studio-regarding-actionbarsherlock/16578217#16578217)

Below is the detail which will hopefully also work in your case. **Specifically check step 4)**

The steps below allowed me to get `ActionBarSherlock` running with no issues.

**1)** Download latest ABS here: [http://actionbarsherlock.com/][1]

**2)** Extract ABS you should have a directory in there called "actionbarsherlock". Copy that to your Android Studio workspace. and rename to `ActionBarSherlock (changed casing)` -- > I now have my Android Studio Projects under `\*documents*\Android Workspace\` As opposed to `\Eclipse Workspace\`

So you should now have something like :

`\*documents*\Android Workspace\ActionBarSherlock\`

Along with your main project maybe:

`\*documents*\Android Workspace\TestProject\`

**3)** Open Android Studio load your `TestProject` then goto `File> Import Module..`. Now navigate to ActionBarSherlock under `\*documents*\Android Workspace\ActionBarSherlock\`
Click Ok and next all the way to finish. It will ask if you want to set a dependancy to the new Module (or at least mine did) click OK

**4)** at this point when compiling I was getting errors in `\ActionBarSherlock\test\` complaining about `Junit`. I simply deleted the `\Test\` directory from my ABS Module under project view. `Right click \test\ > Delete...`. You could also include the junit jar file but I don't think its necessary

**5)** you should now be able to compile without errors