# ActionBarSherlock (library) on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-library, android-studio

I had the problem like wired00 on [Problems importing project into Android Studio regarding ActionBarSherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577580/problems-importing-project-into-android-studio-regarding-actionbarsherlock/16777553#16777553)

I do exactly the solution (Edit2) but when I run I get

```
Gradle: package com.actionbarsherlock.app does not exist
```

Strange thing is that on code I don't get any error, just on compiling.

**Update 1:**

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

Module Settings:

[image: Module Settings of Main Project]

Structure:

[image: Structure Project]

Error:

[image: Compiling error]

Comment: Just like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593391/android-studio-and-using-external-library-projects. I'm on OSX

Comment: Another one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768020/android-studio-adding-actionbarsherlock

Comment: If you could post a screen shot of your project structure and maybe your main project build.gradle file I might be able to help. Having some problems myself but have gotten through this part.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add the following dependency in you gradle file:

compile project(':StoKit:actionbarsherlock')

(within the dependency section)

EDIT 25/05/2013

Ok, so this is my project structure which is currently compiling fine in android studio and via gradle command line:

[image: Project Structure]

EDIT 31/05/2013

Ok, so my build.gradle file within DecisionBuddy-DecisionBuddy module is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:actionbarsherlock')
    compile files('libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar')
    compile files('libs/mobileservices-0.2.0.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

And the one in the actionbarsherlock module is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile files('../../DecisionBuddy/libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

Does this help?

Also make sure you updated to the latest version of the tools - I was having some issues until I did that.

Comment: Gradle: 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file '/Users/Development/Android/Source/Stokit/Stokit/build.gradle' line: 13
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':Stokit'.
> Project with path ':Stokit:actionbarsherlock' could not be found in project ':Stokit'.

Comment: actionbarsherlock need to be on Stokit folder?
Can you share a project working with actionbarsherlock on Android Studio, please?

Comment: Yes thats right, the actionbarsherlock module needs to be within the project (in your case the stokit project). I don't have a project to show with me at the minute, but I can put one up later.

Comment: I moved it to Stokit folder and try it but still the same gradle error. Then I change to `compile project('actionbarsherlock')`. Close Android Studio and do it again and always the same. Please share a simple project when possible, if you don't mind. Thanks for your help

Comment: Added the builg.gradle files to the example provided

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solve it by adding

```
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
```

to the dependencies of the build.gradle of the slidingMunu library project.

here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
      }
      }
}
```