# How to import Actionbar Sherlock library in new latest version of Android Studio

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-studio, android-library

I have updated Android Studio to build # AI-130.72944. I have noticed that it has some how different file structure from the previous release.

I m trying to import the Actionbar Sherlock in my project but not succeeded. I have tried this:

[Problems importing project into Android Studio regarding ActionBarSherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577580/problems-importing-project-into-android-studio-regarding-actionbarsherlock)

Answer (score 1):

If your ActionBarSherlock library doesn't contain a `build.gradle` file, grab it from here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/dev/actionbarsherlock/build.gradle. Save this file into the root directory of the library.

If you're referencing the library from outside of your project directory, you should define where the library is in `settings.gradle`, like so...

```
project(':actionbarsherlock').projectDir = new File('/path/to/library')
```

and then right before that line, you should have: `include ':actionbarsherlock'`

Now, in your `build.gradle` file, include the following...

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':actionbarsherlock')
}
```

Now you should be able to build with Gradle. If you're unfamiliar with Gradle, start reading about it here: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide.html